# Make Dell Latitude D830 video card work with Directx 9.0

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, dvd, graphics-card, directx

I recently updated to Windows 7 64-bit from XP on my Dell Latitude D830. Now I am not able to watch dvd's because it says the video card does not support DirectX 9.0.  Is there an easy way to fix this or do I have to find a new video card?

Answer (score 2):

What DVD player software are you using?  It might be too old to run in Windows 7 (or 64-bit) and is probably unable to properly detect the DirectX 11 that comes with Windows 7.

Both the Intel X3100 and Quadro NVS135/140 graphics are DirectX 10 hardware -- all of which would fill both the software's requirement of having at least DX9 hardware and DX9 libraries installed.

Perhaps make sure you have the latest driers installed.

Dell drivers for both nVidia and Intel : http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&s=bsd&ServiceTag=&SystemID=LATITUDE%20D830&os=WW1&osl=en&catid=&impid=

Intel drivers here : http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18228&ProdId=2800&lang=eng

nVidia drivers here : http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook_winvista_win7_x64_195.62_whql.html

Comment: Good points.  However, we have had issues using drivers from nVidia directly on D830s in the past.  Dell ones are fine but we have had several systems not boot or boot to a blank screen after using nVidia drivers.  Just enter servcie tag at Dell to get their drivers. If that does not work, I would then look to the manufacturer.

Comment: I've heard this before, I used the nVidia drivers and Intel drivers on Dell notebooks before and haven't had much issue.  I've edited my post to include Dell's drivers too.

Comment: i don't think it's a driver issue, more likely the missing directx9 runtimes, they can be downloaded for windows 7 here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=2DA43D38-DB71-4C1B-BC6A-9B6652CD92A3&displaylang=en

Comment: Really? I didn't think it was possible to have Windows install without DirectX, and I always thought newer ones were backwards compatible.  I still suspect he might be trying to use a crusty old PowerDVD or WinDVD that worked in XP, but might be too old to run in 7.

Comment: @krhainos: you're probably right that it's player software, but a default Win (of any version) install won't necessarily include all the latest DirectX runtimes.  it's a good idea to make sure those are up-to-date when updating the drivers.

Comment: He doesn't mention which Windows 7 he upgraded to -- but, I could've sworn that all editions of Windows 7 came with DVD playback included.  If that's the case, I don't see why the OP wouldn't use it.  Maybe the third party player offers features that WMP doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

What video card does the D830 have now?  Could have integrated or nVidia Quadro 135M or 140M I believe.

Do you have the latest Dell drivers or just the MS ones that came with Windows? Grab what you can from Dell.  Might be Vista but may be better than MS.  Worth a try